# Code for displaying thumbnail images

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a simple PHP script that enables users to upload images on a server. I am after some help in displaying these images as thumbnails in an HTMl page and then letting the user click on these thumbnails and then the original picture is displayed in a new page.

Can I use straight HTML for this? Or do I need some combination of javascript or PHP variant?

I know that there are many questions about this on stackoverflow, and I have tried them, but nothing is what I am after.

I would prefferably like the thumbnails be created on the 'fly' rather than me personally having to create each thumbnal when a user uploads an image.

So basically what language should I use to do this? And also can I have some source code if possible?

thanks

Comment: You need to split your task to several smaller and solve them step-by-step. No one ever build a rocket from one solid piece of metal

Comment: You might fine lightbox useful for the popup of the original image http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Answer (score 0):

Creating thumbnails every time they are requested is a very bad idea - it takes a *lot* of processing power, which would be easily saved by keeping them around the first time you create them. I would suggest putting the thumbnail creation in the php script that processes the file upload, so that you save the image and its thumbnail to disk at the same time. You can also keep the thumbnail in memory, or wait until the first time it's requested to create it, but either way you cannot re-generate it every time it is requested.

It is possible to use html to change an image's size, by simply setting the width and/or height properties:

```
<img src='foo.jpg' alt='foo' width='500' height='300'/>
```

However, this is a bad idea if you aren't certain that the user will later want to view the full-sized image. The reason is that a thumbnail has a smaller filesize than the full image: if the client only wants to view the thumbnail, then you don't want to waste bandwidth (= your money and the client's time) sending them the full image.

As for your interface, you don't need javascript to accomplish that, just html. However, you will need a server-side script to create the thumbnails that your html page links to.

Comment: OK, thank you. Is there a simple script available that will display all the images in a folder (that is located on a server) and then display them in a web page?

Comment: Most servers don't require a plugin to list the files in a directory - just navigate to that directory on your website. Of course, that will only display links, not thumbnails. I don't know of a ready-made plugin to address your entire problem - you will have to look into solving it in parts.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of php thumbnail scripts out there.

Either you use a rewriter to still show the original path, but server a php thumbnail version. Or you have to have the url change to something like:

```
<img src="thumb.php?file=path/to/picture.jpg&size=128" />
```

[Mighty Stuff](http://mightystuff.net/php-thumbnail-script)

[phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/)

Are just such two. Best configured to utilize the cached folder. I use a modified version of the first script at work.

Comment: I am playing around with the Mighty Stuff code, but am having problems initiating the //script configuration section... Can I please have some guidance on this? I have the thumb.php file in a folder on the server. I am wanting to create a thumbnail of an image called Winter.jpg and place it in a folder called /thumbnails/ that is one folder up from the directory with the thumb.php file.

Comment: Every file you want to create a thumbnail of should be relative to the thumb script. So do all the ../ etc you need. Also make sure you are specifying the size of the thumbnail. Lastly, go to the thumbnail directly and make sure php errors are turned on to see if it complains at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a PHP script you can build appon only works with jpg images.

It will scan through a directory, normalize the image to a decent dimension and also make a thumb on the fly, then on next refresh it wont need to reprocess the image as its already present in the thumbs dir. Hope it helps...

Script placement

```
Root>
    thisscript.php
    /images/
           someimage.jpg
           someimage2.jpg
```

thisscript.php

```
<?php
// config section
$path = "./images/";
$thpath = $path."thumbs/";
// end configration

// Open the directory
$do = dir($path);
// now check if the thumb dir is available if not, create it!!
if (!is_dir($thpath)){
    mkdir($thpath);
}

$output = '<div>';
while (($file = $do->read()) !== false){
    if (is_dir($path.$file)){
        continue;
    }else{
        $info = pathinfo($path.$file);
        $fileext = $info['extension'];
        if (strtolower($fileext) == 'jpg'){
            if (!is_file($thpath.$file)){           
                //Normalize Super lrg Image to 750x550          
                thumb_it($path, $file, $path,750,550,99);
                //Make Thumb 200x125
                thumb_it($path, $file, $thpath,200,125,99);

                $output .='<p><a href="'.$path.$file.'"><img src="'.$thpath.$file.'" title="" alt="" /></a></p>';
            }else{

                $output .='<p><a href="'.$path.$file.'"><img src="'.$thpath.$file.'" title="" alt="" /></a></p>';
            }
        }
    }
}
$output .='</div>';

echo $output;

//Functions
function thumb_it($dirn, $file, $thumbdir,$rwidth,$rheight,$quality){
    set_time_limit(0);

    $filename = $dirn.$file;
    $thfilename = $thumbdir.preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]/s', '_', $file);
    // get the filename and the thumbernail directory
    if (is_file($filename)){
        // create the thumbernail from the original picture
        $im = @ImageCreateFromJPEG($filename);
        if($im==false){return false;}
        $width = ImageSx($im); // Original picture width is stored
        $height = ImageSy($im); // Original picture height is stored

        if (($width < $rwidth) && ($height < $rheight)){
            $n_height = $height;
            $n_width = $width;
        }else{
            // saveing the aspect ratio
            $aspect_x = $width / $rwidth;
            $aspect_y = $height / $rheight;

            if ($aspect_x > $aspect_y){
                $n_width = $rwidth;
                $n_height = $height / $aspect_x;

            }else{
                $n_height = $rheight;
                $n_width = $width / $aspect_y;
            }
        }

        $newimage = imagecreatetruecolor($n_width, $n_height);
        // resizing the picture
        imageCopyResized($newimage, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $n_width, $n_height, $width, $height);
        // writing to file the thumbnail
        if(file_exists($thfilename)){chmod($thfilename, 0777);}
        Imagejpeg($newimage, $thfilename, $quality);
        imagedestroy($newimage);
        imagedestroy($im);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Lawrence. I have kept the script exactly as you have posted and have placed it in a folder that has some images. The page runs with no errors, yet I cannot see any folders with any thumbnails. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: create a folder called `images` then put all the images in it. look at the config bit at the top

Comment: is the images folder in the same directory as the php script?

Comment: Sorry, should it be "./images/" or "/images/"? Doesn't "./images/" mean a directory under the php script in a folder called "images"?

Comment: yes relative to the scripts location so `./`, so if the script is in a directory called gallery then the images folder is also in that directory, if you use absolute path then it will mess up the output path as you cant have a link like `a href="/srv/www/somesite.com/public_html/images/image.jpg"`