# Photo gallery php code

Tags: php, html, css

I am looking at this page: http://davidwalsh.name/generate-photo-gallery

It has some code to create a php gallery. Can I please have some help in compiling the code into a working file that works? I see the code that is there, I am just a bit confused about how to combine it all together.

thanks

Comment: what is the exact issue you are getting. It is difficult to help you only with this much information

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code for displaying thumbnail images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475938/code-for-displaying-thumbnail-images)

Comment: A working file that works, brought to your by the redundant department of redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i did for the working model-

1)Created Folder/files structure under my xampp/htdocs/photogallery 
folders under this structure-

- preload-images(Folder)
- preload-images-thumbs(Folder)
- index.php
- mootools-1.2.4.js
- smoothbox.css
- smoothbox.js
- style.css
- test.php

**preload-images** Folder contains jpg images(this what to be placed under this folder, unless you will get "No image to display" message)

**preload-images-thumbs** automatically generates thumbnail for the images under previous folder images

My **index.php** contains link to these files- smoothbox.css, style.css, mootools-1.2.4.js, smoothbox.js (source of these files, I extracted from the site demo)

Then I included php file as include_once('test.php'); with following code--

```
/** settings **/
$images_dir = 'preload-images/';
$thumbs_dir = 'preload-images-thumbs/';
$thumbs_width = 200;
$images_per_row = 3;

/** generate photo gallery **/
$image_files = get_files($images_dir);
if(count($image_files)) {
    $index = 0;
    foreach($image_files as $index=>$file) {
        $index++;
        $thumbnail_image = $thumbs_dir.$file;
        if(!file_exists($thumbnail_image)) {
            $extension = get_file_extension($thumbnail_image);
            if($extension) {
                make_thumb($images_dir.$file,$thumbnail_image,$thumbs_width);
            }
        }
        echo '<a href="',$images_dir.$file,'" class="photo-link smoothbox" rel="gallery"><img src="',$thumbnail_image,'" /></a>';
        if($index % $images_per_row == 0) { echo '<div class="clear"></div>'; }
    }
    echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
}
else {
    echo '<p>There are no images in this gallery.</p>';
}
```

Under **test.php** i placed this content--

```
/* function:  generates thumbnail */
function make_thumb($src,$dest,$desired_width) {
    /* read the source image */
    $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $width = imagesx($source_image);
    $height = imagesy($source_image);
    /* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
    $desired_height = floor($height*($desired_width/$width));
    /* create a new, "virtual" image */
    $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width,$desired_height);
    /* copy source image at a resized size */
    imagecopyresized($virtual_image,$source_image,0,0,0,0,$desired_width,$desired_height,$width,$height);
    /* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */
    imagejpeg($virtual_image,$dest);
}

/* function:  returns files from dir */
function get_files($images_dir,$exts = array('jpg')) {
    $files = array();
    if($handle = opendir($images_dir)) {
        while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            $extension = strtolower(get_file_extension($file));
            if($extension && in_array($extension,$exts)) {
                $files[] = $file;
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    return $files;
}

/* function:  returns a file's extension */
function get_file_extension($file_name) {
    return substr(strrchr($file_name,'.'),1);
}
```

Now Run the code from your server, and let me know if u have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

You won't have to compile anything. You just need to upload your code on a server that supports php.
Or you can install XAMMP or WAMP on your PC/laptop.

http://www.wampserver.com/en/